# How to delete a document in scribd.com using scribd-fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delete-file, scribd

Can I delete a document that uploaded to scribd.com using Rails scribd-fu??

Answer (score 1):

Yap, you can.

```
your_model.destroy_ipaper_document
```

Taken from:

http://github.com/mdarby/scribd_fu/blob/master/lib/scribd_fu.rb

Comment: Thanks for information. But should it be just Model.destroy(doc_id)??? the destroy_ipaper_document method seems to be privated.

Answer (score -1):

You must click your icon, which is located in the upper right corner of your screen next to the button "read free for 30 days." There, you will see the "documents upload" button, which will take you to a page where you may view all of your uploaded documents and completely erase them from Scribd.

Comment: This question appears to be about the RubyGem scribd_fu, not scribd itself. You might want to revise your answer to address that.